# How to use ModifierKeys in a class

Tags: .net, vb.net

I need to access "ModifierKeys" from a class, not from a form (I have a reference to that form, but frm.Modifierkeys is not allowed from the class). Is that possible, and if yes, how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ModifierKeys is static so you should be able to just call

```
Control.ModifierKeys
```

Otherwise you can PInvoke the GetKeyState method.

Answer (score 0):

If you can pass `KeyEventArgs` to your class (from a `KeyUp` or `KeyDown` event handler), you have access to the [`KeyEventArgs.Modifiers`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keyeventargs.modifiers%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) property.

Comment: Thanks, that might be handy too :)